# How do I extract code from redirected url? (OAuth 2.0, Flask)

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0

So the authorization request url is correct and it successfully redirects to `redirect_url` which is `/loginAuthorized`. I can plainly see that a `code` is added as in

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/loginAuthorized/?code=SOME_CODE`
```

but can't grab it on the code. When I print `path`, it just prints `loginAuthorized/` wihtout `code`. I can ask users to manually copy paste code from url, but it will not be convenient so want to avoid asking that.

```
import re
import requests
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main():

    # encoded url with information needed to request an authorization
    url = "https://kauth.kakao.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5000%2F%2FloginAuthorized/&response_type=code"
    return render_template('index.html', request_url=url) 

# If you authorize the service, it redirected to this url
# Catch any url that has /loginAuthorized as its base
@app.route("/loginAuthorized", defaults={"path": ""})
@app.route("/<path:path>")
def loginAuthorized(path):
    print('a')
    print(path)  # "loginAuthorized/" is printed, there is no code
    print('b')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `request` flask module to get query params from URL

Import `request` using

`from flask import request`

Then to get code query param from URL use.
`request.args.get('code')`

Comment: That was much easier than I thought. Thank you. (p.s. This module is needed `from flask import request`)

Comment: Updated answer.